# Using custom style in Firemonkey makes component disappear?

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-xe, delphi-xe8, firemonkey-style

1. Dropped TStyleBook on the form and loaded custom style from Embarcadero (not my own)
2. Set Form.StyleBook to that TStyleBook component
3. Drop button on the form and it looks styled
4. Move button around or change any property and button disappears
5. Drop TGroupBox and move it around, click off  on the form and border around GroupBox is gone.

When I switch between Code and then back to Design tab - components show back up styled as they should ???

Really odd. Any ideas? Here is the video: http://screencast.com/t/tniPIANDNK